# Como obtener los datos de usuario de PhpMyAdmin en cPanel

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Alguien sabe como obtener los datos de usuario y contraseña de phpmyadmin en el cPanel, estoy usando el eHosting, direccion: http://solucionesinmobiliariasjemar.com.ve

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes acceso al cpanel, te vas al apartado de base de datos y ahí encontrarás algo como **Bases de datos MySQL**. Dentro de este apartado podrás ver todas las bases de datos MySQL y los usuarios asociados.

No es posible ver la contraseña actual de un usuario de la base de datos desde el cpanel, pero si puedes modificarla o crear un nuevo usuario.

Otra opción, si necesitas averiguar la clave de acceso, es revisar los archivos del proyecto y buscar donde esta confugurado el acceso a la base de datos, ahí debe de estar puesta la contraseña en texto plano, claro esto siempre y cuando exista un proyecto en funcionamiento sobre la base de datos que queremos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, enrealidad la contraseña master es la que me enviaron por correo, solo que pense que era para acceder al cPnel, y que las demas carácteristicas tenian usuarios y contraseñas diferentes